# Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Коллеги, подскажите:
имеется строка с датой вида: `Fri Oct 06 15:54:33 MSK 2017`
пытаюсь её превратить в `java.sql.Date`:

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
 Date date = format.parse("Fri Oct 06 15:54:33 MSK 2017");
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

по итогу в переменой sqlDate:2017-10-06.
пытаюсь вставить значение в базу:

```
preparedStmt.setDate(1, sqlDate);
```

на выходе ошибка

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect
>   datetime value: 'Fri Oct 06 15:54:33 MSK 2017' for column

что я делаю не так?

Comment: MySQL понимает только следующие форматы даты-времени: строковые 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', 'YY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS', 'YYYYMMDDHHMMSS' и 'YYMMDDHHMMSS', и числовые YYYYMMDDHHMMSS и YYMMDDHHMMSS. Любые другие форматы требуют явной конвертации функцией STR_TO_DATE().